# comparison of linear Q-learning and DQN

Tags: linear-regression, logistic-regression, dqn, game, openai-gym

I saw in ***DQN nature paper 2015*** `https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14236`(Extended Data Table 4) some comparisons between ***DQN*** and  ***linear Q-learning***. 
[image: Extended Data Table 4]

The ***ratio of reward*** for different games are very different. For instance I saw the ratio of reward of ***Linear Q-learning*** is between 3.8 to 100 times more than DQN? What is the reason of this big difference? How we can clarify this? Is it related to complexity or sensitivity of game? I am not very familiar with complexity and properties of these games.

In addition, in Extended Data Table 2 of this paper it has written it is compared with best linear learner?

Would you please explained this sentence:***"Best Linear Learner is the best result obtained by a linear function approximator on different types of hand designed feature"***

What is the meaning that by ***best***? The best results during test of linear? Because I only know one ***linear regression***

> y=ax+b

, I only replace the ***DNN*** section of ***DQN*** with a ***linear regression*** (i.e. just input and output and linear without any hidden layer) I am confused with best word in this table.
[image: Extended Data Table 2]

Also, do you have seen the comparison with ***Logistic Regression Q-learning***? (What I mean by logistic regression Q-learning is to repalce the ***deep neural network section*** of **DQN** with a **Sigmoid** function between input and output without any hidden layer) What is the ratio of result of this approach in comparison with ***DQN***?

Comment: Q-learning involves a regression, not a classification, so logisitic regression wouldn't really make sense.  Logistic regression would be the baseline for policy learning.  Good question though about what the linear learner is!

Comment: That's what I mean - the q function should return a real number between + and - infinity; logistic regression is squashed between 0 and 1

Comment: @neil-slater do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @ Neil Slater
 do you have any suggestion?